# Correct folder & file permisson for WordPress

Tags: installation

I used `find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;` & `find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`  for my WordPress.

[image]

But when I tried to install WordPress I got below message.

[image]

When I tried to update a plugin I got `Update failed: Could not create directory. /home/foysal/www/html/wordprac/plugin_test/wordpress/wp-content/upgrade` error.

[image]

What are the correct file and folder permission for WordPress ? Which mistake I am doing here ?

Comment: Are the folders owned by the user the webserver/PHP is using?

Comment: Thanks @kero. How to do that ?

Comment: See [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096255/what-permissions-for-php-scripts-directories) or similar. It depends on your web server (usually Apache or NGINX) and PHP(-FPM) configuration. But this is not in scope of this stack (as it is not about WordPress, but (PHP-)webservers in general)